# Line break not working in d3.js after using html too

Tags: d3.js

I have tried implementing the html for linebreak. Still its not working. Can anybody clear this?

```
   d3.select('svg g.chart #countryLabel')
        .html("ID:"+d.Patient_id+" ["+d[xAxis]+","+d[yAxis]+"] ")
        .transition();
```

output:

```
D:384 [135,63]
```

I want to break this as

```
ID:384 
[135,63]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

finally sorted out it as this

```
d3.select('svg g.chart #countryLabel')
    text_node = d3.select('#countryLabel')
    //.html("")
    .append('tspan')
    .text("ID:"+d.Patient_id+" ["+d[xAxis]+","+d[yAxis]+"]")
    .attr('dx', '.2em')
    text_node.append('tspan')
    .text('another line')
     .attr('dx', '.0em')
    .attr('dy', '.9em')
    text_node.append('tspan')
    .text('another line')
      .attr('dx', '.0em')
    .attr('dy', '.9em')
      .transition();
```